# How to create a central class sending messages via JMS in a web application in TomEE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jndi, apache-tomee, tomee-7

Say I have a web application that I deploy to a TomEE (Plume 7.0.2). For this application I want to create a central class responsible for sending messages via JMS. My first idea was to create a servlet without mapping, which gets the required fields injected:

```java
public class JMSSendingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/logging")
    private Queue loggingQueue;

    @Resource
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public void sendMessage(String text) throws JMSException {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        //and so on...
        producer.send(message);
    }
}
```

However in order to access this method from the rest of the application I would need either to make the method and the fields static or to get the instance of that servlet somehow. Since I can't (or shouldn't) perform dependency injection on static fields I'm trying to find a solution for the second option. Here's my attempt:

```java
public class JMSSendingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static JMSSendingServlet instance;

    //...

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        instance = this;
        super.init(config);
    }

    public static JMSSendingServlet getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}

//usage:
public class SomeClass {

    public void someMethod() {
        JMSSendingServlet.getInstance().sendMessage("Hello");
    }
}
```

Since I don't have any mappings for this servlet and it gets loaded it via `<load-on-startup/>` there should exist only one instance of it. But I still feel kinda uncomfortable with that solution. It looks to dirty to me, at least because `getInstance` can return null.

Would it be cleaner (if possible) to relinquish dependency injection and to use JNDI to obtain a `ConnectionFactory` and a `Queue`? Are there other maybe better solutions?

Comment: What version of TomEE are you using?

Comment: @SteveC The latest stable Plume 7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

why not having a JMSService class with the injections and a send(xxx) method and injecting this class where you need (servlet, jaxrs service, MDB, other...)?

CDI would make it cleaner IMO than relying on servlets